# Applying style to jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a JQueryUI Autocomplete widget which is working good. Now I am applying this:

> http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css

and imported it to the page. How should I access this theme in my jQueryUI? Here is my jQueryUI code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $('[id$="tbSearch"]').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags

    });
});
```

Can someone provide me with some guidance? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just work if you have the theme's css included on your page (and have the correct path to images within the CSS).

Try downloading a custom package from here: http://jqueryui.com/download

You can pick the theme on the right, and it will be packaged with your javascript code and images.

**EDIT**:

Your HTML should include something like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/myStyles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I downloaded that. Now where should I refer in my JQuery?

Comment: So, copy the downloaded (and unzipped) files to your project (you'll only need the `css` and `js` directories.  Use relative paths in your HTML to point to the different files within your project.